# Zookeeper Maximum Latency Monitoring Thresholds

Tags: apache-zookeeper, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

A red-flagged error message appeared suddenly in the Zookeeper section of my Cloudera Manager Interface 
"Bad: Maximum request latency: 102,477 ms. Maximum client-negotiable session timeout: 50,000 ms. Percentage of maximum client-negotiable session timeout: 204.95%. Critical threshold: 100.00%"
.

I have noticed that those values "102,477", "204.95%" are static and don't change at all in that message.

How to get rid of the message? it's corrupt the beauty of my CM (the view of all working fine in  my cluster )

I've tried the restart solution and  clean the logs and the but no change

Any help or indication would be appreciated.

CDH  :5.14.2

CM :Cloudera Express 5.14.1